# Disabling Host-to-Guest time sync in EC2 windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, xen, time, time-synchronization

In an EC2 instance (Xen Virtualized) is it possible to disable time sync on a Guest VM by Host VM.

I found that it can be done on Linux instance by modifying xen.independent_wallclock=1

Is there any similar way to do it for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration to do that task in Windows.

We achieved it by having our own NTP server with required time set & configured the Windows instance to sync time from our own NTP server.